# jquery empty method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check the code below:

```
<script>
 var cls = ['', 'a', 'a b', 'a b c'];
var divs = $('div.wrap').children();
```

note that children() performs a destructive opration i.e it constructs a new jquery object

```
var appendClass = function() {
 divs.append(function() {
return '<div>' + (this.className || 'none') + '</div>';
});
};

appendClass();

$('button').bind('click', function() {
var tc = this.className || undefined;
divs.toggleClass(tc);
appendClass();
});

$('a').bind('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

//(children is a destructive method which have constructed new jquery object so what is the use of using empty method on the upcoming statement) 
divs.empty().each(function(i) {
this.className = cls[i];
});
 appendClass();
});
```

so what is the use for using empty method on *divs* variable ??

Comment: Maybe the documentation might be helpful: http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)method :

> This method removes not only child (and other descendant) elements,
>   but also any text within the set of matched elements. This is because,
>   according to the DOM specification, any string of text within an
>   element is considered a child node of that element.

Use Cases

1. you want to clear all the existing data and append the new data.
2. Useful for templates, where you manipulate data .

   ```
    divs.empty().each(function(i) {
   this.className = cls[i];
   });
   ```

above code is useless, as div get emptied, after that if you loop also no elements will found. i don't know what markup you have, but above code will not useful.

Comment: no i meant say that since divs has only child element so how can we use an empty method?it dont have the parent element